# Android Galxy Tab Runtime exception :native typeface cannot be made?

Tags: android, typeface, galaxy-tab

I'm trying to use custom fonts
It works on emulator with no isses.

But on Smsung Galaxy Tab is throwing following error:
native typeface cannot be made

Here is my code:

```
               public static Typeface typeface;
             // -----define typeface

    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Verdana.TTf");
    Typeface.class.getField("DEFAULT").setAccessible(true);
                          ---------------------
        lblBrandCategory1.setTypeface(GuestActivity.typeface, 4);


            anyone knows the solution???
```

Comment: no.. I'm still searching...so finally I'm using default fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I had this (on a Galaxy Tab as it happens) doing pretty much exactly what you're doing.  Turned out to be a case-sensitivity issue for me, e.g. filename was all lowercase and I capitalized the .ttf filename in the java code.

So presumably that means that you get this error whenever the ttf can't be found (so check your path is good as well).

Comment: Quite likely the case of OP, since the extension is TTf - which seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I don't believe it's device dependent.

I solved it by making sure of the following:

1. If you have more than one project, make sure your font file is stored in the assets folder of your **main project** - not a dependency project.
2. for safety, rename your font to all lowercase and reference it as such in your code.

   `FontUtils.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "fonts/arimo-regular.ttf");`

Here is a class to override the default font for my entire application.

```
public class FontUtils {

/**
 * Sets the default font.
 *
 * @param context the context
 * @param staticTypefaceFieldName the static typeface field name
 * @param fontAssetName the font asset name
 */
public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
        String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typefaces.get(context, fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

/**
 * Replace a font.
 *
 * @param staticTypefaceFieldName the static typeface field name
 * @param newTypeface the new typeface
 */
protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field StaticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        StaticField.setAccessible(true);
        StaticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class Typefaces {

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                            assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not get typeface '" + assetPath + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
}
```